# CiviMember : default confirmation message not sent

Tags: civimember, mailing

When I am creating manually a new membership, if I check the confirmation mail checkbox no default message is not sent. Do I need to configure something ?

Comment: Are any mails being sent from the system?

Comment: Yes, I can send mail to any contact thru CiviCRM.